# jqueryMobile Dialog opens every time on pageshow even with cookie set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

My jQuery mobile dialog opens every time the page is loaded. Even with a cookie set to only have it open once and never again it continues to open on every refresh. I have no idea why it loads without any triggers? Any help would be appreciated.

JAVASCRIPT

```
function openDialog() {
var interval = setInterval(function(){
       $.mobile.changePage('#dialog');
       clearInterval(interval);
},1);  
}

$(function() {
if ($.cookie('dialog_shown') == null) {
   $.cookie('dialog_shown', 'yes', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
        $(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){   
            openDialog();   
        }); 
    } 
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div data-role="dialog">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
        <h1>Custom Dialog</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Customize the HTML. Have any content you want in here.</h1>
        <p>This is a regular page, styled as a dialog. To create a dialog, just link to a normal page and include a transition and <code>data-rel="dialog"</code> attribute.</p>
        <a href="#index" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Button Style</a>       
        <a href="#index" data-role="button" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="index">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery mobile will load the first page or dialog in the body when no page is selected.
so your HTML should be like this:

```
<body>

   <div data-role="page" id="index">
   </div>

   <div data-role="dialog">
    .......
   </div>

</body>
```

second thing is if cookie doesn't exists, it will return `undefined` not `null`.
so:

```
if ($.cookie('dialog_shown') === undefined) { ..}
```

third thing is you didn't set the id of the dialog:

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">
```

your code should be:

```
   $(document).delegate('#index','pageshow',  function(){   
      if ($.cookie('dialog_shown') === undefined) {
           $.cookie('dialog_shown', 'yes', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
           openDialog();
      }      
   });
```

Comment: Hmm. Now it doesn't load at all even after are cookies deleted.

Comment: still doesn't load at all. I've been doing console logs and I can't get anything to log in the if statement. It isn't even firing. [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8859129/HSSV-2013/HSSV-2013/index.html

Comment: remove $(function.. and use `delegate()` instead of `on`, updated the answer

Comment: I see that works in FireFox, doesn't work at all in Safari and in Chrome is just keeps re-opening the dialog on close.